# log-likelihood: changing relative contribution of two summation terms

Tags: probability, probability-theory, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

Suppose I have a log-likelihood of the form
$$\mathcal{L} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i + \sum_{j = 1}^{m} b_j,$$
where $a_i$ and $b_j$ are some independent log-probabilities. The problem is, the second sum $\sum b_j$ has much smaller contribution than the first one ($m \ll n$ and $|a_i|$ is usually bigger than $|b_j|$).

Obviously, the second summation can be multiplied by some weight $C$, but I have several questions:

- Are there any methods to find weight $C$ in advance? (sizes $n,m$ and distributions $a,b$ are known),
- Are there different techniques to equalize contribution of different terms in log-likelihood?